# How could you measure the minimum and maximum distance to the outer edge of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, measurements, workflow

I am looking for a automatic method to measure the minimum and maximum distance from a point (represented by the star) to the outer edge of a polygon (black dotted line).

I know this could be done with the measure tool but this can have accuracy issues and is a manual process.

Are there any plugins that do this of the shelf or could anyone recommend a workflow model or script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the nodes of your polygon and then build a distance matrix from your point to the nodes - that would be my approach.

Comment: I assume I would have to dissolve to polygon first?

Comment: There's no reason to do so, as far as I know - but be my guest and try both ways, maybe the outcome is different? Could be useful, depending on your data structure.